# How to execute a for loop after a for loop ends in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting an API response and iterating it through a for loop and inside that for loop there are multiple if else if loops based on different conditions.

I have one more for loop, which is written after the first for loop ends, but the second for loop runs as many times as the first for loop runs.

That is the main reason why I went for a separate for loop but it is not working.

```js
async function doGetRequest() {
  var filteredArr = [];
  var unique = [];
  var cosmos = [{
      "_id": "63773144c3160f782c087e35",
      "nfrid": "637328ebf5c4b2558b064809",
      "nfrname": "azuread",
      "fileName": "index.js",
      "isImport": true,
      "isConst": false,
      "isComponent": false,
      "isNewFile": false,
      "isPackage": false,
      "landmark": null,
      "isAfter": null,
      "fileContent": "import { MsalProvider } from '@azure/msal-react';import { msalConfig } from './authConfig';import {PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';",
      "filePath": "src/index.js",
      "isIndexHtml": false,
      "projecttypeid": "6372366d1b568e00d8af2e44",
      "projecttypetitle": "PWA React",
      "isReplace": false,
      "nfrGitIo": [{
        "_id": "637328ebf5c4b2558b064809",
        "iconpath": "https://cdnerapidxdevportal.azureedge.net/webdesignerimages/azure-active-directory-aad-icon-488x512-3d71nrtk.png",
        "title": "Azure AD",
        "description": "Azure Active Directory (Azure AD), part of Microsoft Entra, is an enterprise identity service that provides single sign-on, multifactor authentication, and conditional access to guard against 99.9 percent of cybersecurity attacks."
      }]
    },
    {
      "_id": "63773195c3160f782c087e36",
      "nfrid": "637328ebf5c4b2558b064809",
      "nfrname": "azuread",
      "fileName": "index.js",
      "isImport": false,
      "isConst": true,
      "isComponent": false,
      "isNewFile": false,
      "isPackage": false,
      "landmark": `("root"));`,
      "isAfter": true,
      "fileContent": "const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);",
      "filePath": "src/index.js",
      "isIndexHtml": false,
      "projecttypeid": "6372366d1b568e00d8af2e44",
      "projecttypetitle": "PWA React",
      "isReplace": false,
      "nfrGitIo": [{
        "_id": "637328ebf5c4b2558b064809",
        "iconpath": "https://cdnerapidxdevportal.azureedge.net/webdesignerimages/azure-active-directory-aad-icon-488x512-3d71nrtk.png",
        "title": "Azure AD",
        "description": "Azure Active Directory (Azure AD), part of Microsoft Entra, is an enterprise identity service that provides single sign-on, multifactor authentication, and conditional access to guard against 99.9 percent of cybersecurity attacks."
      }]
    },
    {
      "_id": "637731a2c3160f782c087e37",
      "nfrid": "637328ebf5c4b2558b064809",
      "nfrname": "azuread",
      "fileName": "index.js",
      "isImport": false,
      "isConst": false,
      "isComponent": true,
      "isNewFile": false,
      "isPackage": false,
      "landmark": "<App />",
      "isAfter": null,
      "fileContent": "<MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}><App /></MsalProvider>",
      "filePath": "src/index.js",
      "isIndexHtml": false,
      "projecttypeid": "6372366d1b568e00d8af2e44",
      "projecttypetitle": "PWA React",
      "isReplace": true,
      "nfrGitIo": [{
        "_id": "637328ebf5c4b2558b064809",
        "iconpath": "https://cdnerapidxdevportal.azureedge.net/webdesignerimages/azure-active-directory-aad-icon-488x512-3d71nrtk.png",
        "title": "Azure AD",
        "description": "Azure Active Directory (Azure AD), part of Microsoft Entra, is an enterprise identity service that provides single sign-on, multifactor authentication, and conditional access to guard against 99.9 percent of cybersecurity attacks."
      }]
    }
  ];

  unique = cosmos.map(item => item.fileName).filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index);
  console.log(unique);

  const seen = new Set();
  filteredArr = cosmos.filter(el => {
    const duplicate = seen.has(el.fileName);
    seen.add(el.fileName);
    return !duplicate;
  });

  try {
    for (let index = 0; index < cosmos.length; index++) {
      for (let i = 0; i < unique.length; i++) {
        if (cosmos[index].fileName === unique[i]) {
          if (cosmos[index].isPackage === true) {
            var statusPackage = "import";
            console.log(statusPackage);
          } else if (cosmos[index].isImport === true) {
            var statusImport = "pack"
            console.log(statusImport);
          } else if (cosmos[index].isConst === true) {
            var statusConst = "third";
            console.log(statusConst);
          } else if (cosmos[index].isComponent === true) {
            var statusComponent = "okay"
            console.log(statusComponent);
          } else if (cosmos[index].isNewFile === true) {
            var statusNewFile = "okyy";
            console.log(statusNewFile);
          } else if (cosmos[index].isIndexHtml === true) {
            var statusIndexHtml = "kk";
            console.log(statusIndexHtml);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } finally {
    wholeUpdate(filteredArr);
  }
}

function wholeUpdate(filteredArr) {
  for (let index = 0; index < filteredArr.length; index++) {
    var status = common.updateFullContent(filteredArr[index]);
    console.log(status);
  }
}

doGetRequest();
```

The second for loop is the one which is at the end. The variable i am passing in that loop has only one data so it should ideally run only once, but since the first for loop is running three times, this is also running three times.

I am not sure what i am missing here.

Comment: What does `console.log(filteredArr.length)` show?

Comment: If it's running 3 times, there must be 3 items in the array.

Comment: Check for the brackets properly.

Comment: Can you reduce your code to a [mre] that doesn't require packages like axios and commonmethods, so we can test it here?

Comment: console.log(filteredArr.length) shows 1

Comment: I have updated the code without axios

Comment: We can't use `fs` here, either.

Comment: Now it should run, i have updated the code. Even though filteredArr lenght is 1 it is running  three times since cosmos.lenght is 3. Need some help

Comment: There's no function `common.updateFullContent(filteredArr[index])`

Comment: That's simply not possible. The loop is clearly limited by `index < filteredArr.length`

Comment: I removed that line and changed the next line to `console.log(index)` and it only logged once.

Comment: function wholeUpdate(filteredArr) {
    for (let index = 0; index < filteredArr.length; index++) {
        var status = "response running how many times";
        console.log(status);
      }
}

Comment: But when i run the whole function it is running three times

Comment: Can you further explain what the expected result is? -- Based on your current explanation, you would have `for loop` -> `conditions` -> `for loop` , but your code has `for loop` -> `for loop` -> `conditions` -- If you don't want the seceond loop running as often as the first one, you have to restrict it with some conditions between those two loops.